# How to customize HTTP response for WebSocket upgrade request in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, websocket

I have a WebSocket endpoint configured like this in my `WebSocketConfigurer` implementation

```
public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator(myWebSocketHandler), "/ws/")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                .addInterceptors(myHandshakeInterceptor);
    }
```

There are some checks in `myWebSocketHandler#beforeHandshake` and I would like to send an error message to the user in case the server decides to refuse to upgrade the connection. I've tried this

```
response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.BAD_GATEWAY);
try {
    response.getBody().write("Error".getBytes());
    response.getBody().flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
    log.error("Error writing response", e);
}
return false;
```

The status code works, but the body is empty. How can I send it?

EDIT: turns out the problem was that I used Firefox console to check for the response and it didn't show me anything. If I use cURL to make the same request then everything works fine and I see the message I write to the response body!

Comment: How did you check that the body was empty ?

Comment: Spring interceptors are not modifying response body

Comment: I checked the response in Firefox console. Turns out it doesn't show the response body. When I use curl everything works fine and I can read the response.

Comment: You used interceptor or custom handler ?

Answer (score 0):

To update response body you need to write your custom RequestUpateStrategy.
As from spring official documentation from AbstractHandshakeHandler it says that:

```
The actual upgrade is delegated to a server-specific RequestUpgradeStrategy, which will update the response as necessary and initialize the WebSocket.
```

If you are using Tomcat as servlet container you can extend [TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-websocket/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/socket/server/standard/TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy.java)class and provider your own logic how to handle
websocket upgrade.

For each servlet container there is implementation of RequestUpgradeStrategy
[documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/server/support/AbstractHandshakeHandler.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, writing response body in either HandshakeHandler or RequestUpgradeStrategy doesn't work. I still get an empty body.

Comment: Can you please share an example?

Comment: Here is my custom handler and strategy (the code is too long to post in a comment, sorry) https://pastebin.com/scCcnLBU

Comment: Can you share github link ?

Comment: Please look at AbstractHandshakeHandler class method  protected void handleInvalidUpgradeHeader(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response)